# Maintain initial list items order while adding or removing items in it

Tags: java, list, kotlin, linked-list

I need to be able to remove items from the list and insert them back while maintaining the same order. My list begins with initial set of items. New items can't be inserted. So, added-items and max-item-count stays same.

Example:

My initial list is as following

```
0=201, 1=402, 2=952, 3=101, 4=-54, 5=0
```

If I remove items at 2, 4 positions, I have

```
0=201, 1=402, 3=101, 5=0
```

But, when I add items of removed positions back to list; {2, 4}, I have

```
0=201, 1=402, 3=101, 5=0, 2=952, 4=-54
```

I want the items to be added in initial order. i.e.

```
0=201, 1=402, 2=952, 3=101, 4=-54, 5=0
```

They must be in the original order that they were removed in. This is just an example, these values cannot be sorted. They are in the order they were added in.

If you suggest to use a backup list of originals, how do I determine correct adjacent positions to current list? So, if original list has 6 items, and value `-54` is at `4` index. I remove {2, 3, 4} items from list. New list's size changes to 3. I can't add item at `4` index in original list to new list at `4` index. New list will have only {0, 1, 2} as valid positions. Besides, this mightn't even keep order.

So the question is, how can I remove and add elements into a list and make sure that the order is kept?

Also, should this be done with a LinkedList? If yes, how?

*Edit:* Original list is an ArrayList. I can't modify this type. Certainly, I would need to feed it items from another collection after determining correct index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.junit.Test

class Fixing60945040 {

    private val originalItems = mutableListOf(
        201, 402, 952, 101, -54, 19
    )

    /**
     * a backup map of original items
     *
     * Why LinkedHashMap? HashMap works with access-order implementation.
     * Items do not keep insertion order in HashMap. So, inserting original
     * items will look like: 402, 19, 101, -54, 952, 201
     *
     * LinkedHashMap keeps insertion-order by default.
     *
     * Map<Int, Boolean> = (value, hidden)
     *
     * So, items like 201, 402 etc are keys for the map
     * and boolean tells us if this item is visible
     */
    private lateinit var backupMap: LinkedHashMap<Int, Boolean>

    /**
     * create a backup of original items
     */
    private fun createBackupMap(): LinkedHashMap<Int, Boolean> {

        val backupMap = LinkedHashMap<Int, Boolean>()
        for (item in originalItems) {
            backupMap[item] = true
        }
        return backupMap
    }

    private fun removeItem(item: Int) {
        println("Removing: $item")

        assert(originalItems.contains(item)) { "Can't remove an item that doesn't exist in the list." }

        // remove this value from original list
        val modified = originalItems.remove(item)
        if (modified) {
            // item was removed. Now, mark this item as hidden in the backup map
            backupMap[item] = false
        }
    }

    private fun insertItem(item: Int) {
        println("Inserting: $item")

        assert(!originalItems.contains(item)) { "Can't insert duplicate item." }
        assert(backupMap.containsKey(item)) { "Can't insert unknown new item." }

        // mark this item as visible in the backup map
        backupMap[item] = true

        // to know the insertion index, we need to iterate through
        // backup map
        var insertionIndex = 0
        for (entry in backupMap) {

            if (!entry.value /* !isVisible */ ) {
                /* not visible, this item is marked as hidden; ignoring */
                continue
            }

            // Is this key same as the item to be inserted?
            if (entry.key == item) {
                // It is. Insert the item.
                originalItems.add(insertionIndex, item)
                break
            } else {
                // It isn't, increase the index; check the next key.
                insertionIndex++
            }
        }
    }



    @Test
    fun test() {
        backupMap = createBackupMap()

        println("list: $originalItems \n")

        removeItem(952)
        removeItem(-54)
        println("list: $originalItems \n")

        removeItem(101)
        println("list: $originalItems \n")

        insertItem(-54)
        println("list: $originalItems \n")

        insertItem(101)
        println("list: $originalItems \n")

        insertItem(952)
        println("list: $originalItems \n")
    }
}
```

If anyone finds any performance improvement, please comment. If you think there's a better approach, please add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a backup list of originals at first, but in `Map <Index, Map<oldValue, NewValue>>` (As per your requirement). If you remove any item from `ArrayList` mark the New Value as `null` in Map.

Comment: Sorry, can't create a map for every entry.